# Tomcat what is it and how to setup custom web page

Tags: tomcat

I just joined a new company and it was told that the sites they have uses tomcat. And, they want to show a custom web page when tomcat is down. currently it will show Error 500. I am the only person in IT team for now and I am pretty new to web development and do not have knowledge about tomcat. I got no handover from the person who worked previously in my position. I have two questions.

Can someone please explain what is tomcat and why do we need it?
how to setup a custom web page when tomcat is down?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat is a Java application server.

Typically you would host your Tomcat applications behind an HTTP server such as Apache.

What you could do, is create a custom error page to handle 403 errors. This page would need to be added to the HTTP server's configuration. This is just a standard HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

1. Tomcat is a servlet container that is used to serve java (or jvm) web applications.
2. You can setup a "downtime page" only if you have something in front of tomcat - apache or load balancer. So check how to configure your web server or load balancer to display a "downtime page" if the target resource is not returned in a timely manner.